Sync vertical scroll in tabBars viewControllers
I need to sync the vertical content offset for a tabBbar viewControllers. I accomplished this sending a notification on didScroll
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: name, object: self, userInfo: ["offset": scrollView.contentOffset])
}

And the reading it back in viewDidLoad:
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: name, object: nil, queue: .main) { notification in
        let offset = notification.userInfo!["offset"]! as! CGPoint

        if let sender = notification.object as? SyncedViewController, sender != self {
            self.collectionView.contentOffset = offset
        }
    }

Everything works as expected expect one big caveat, you need to tap on each tab in order this to work, otherwise it wont work :(
I also tried to force viewDidLoad using _ = vc.view but with no success.

The issue is due to view controller life-cycle ... the controllers in each tab are not loaded until the tab is selected.
You can confirm this by adding this line at the end of viewDidLoad() in each of your tab controllers:
print("View did load")

and you won't see that print output until you've selected the tab.
To "pre-load" them, add this to the end of viewDidLoad() in your first tab's controller:
if let tabC = self.tabBarController,
   let tabs = tabC.viewControllers
{
    for vc in tabs {
        vc.loadViewIfNeeded()
    }
}
    

That may solve your issue... if not, you probably also need to set the content offset in viewDidLayoutSubviews().
To do that, try adding a property to each of your controllers:
public var theOffset: CGPoint = .zero

then, in viewDidLayoutSubviews():
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    self.collectionView.contentOffset = self.theOffset
}

and update that property in your notification handler:
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: name, object: nil, queue: .main) { notification in
    let offset = notification.userInfo!["offset"]! as! CGPoint

    if let sender = notification.object as? SyncedViewController, sender != self {
        self.collectionView.contentOffset = offset
        self.theOffset = offset
    }
}

If that doesn't work, another approach would be to loop through the controllers array and set the offset directly ... I can give you an example of that if the above still has issues.
